# laravel custom api resource relationships

Tags: json, laravel, api

I have a query that I make to obtain the users, this table is related to 3 others, but the query is a bit long, I would like to handle the JsonResource but I have not been able to generate the JsonResource as I have it in the normal query.

**Method index:**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'users.username', 'users.status', 'users.id_cost_center', 'cost_centers.code AS code_cost_center', 'cost_centers.description AS cost_center', 
                          'users.id_dependence', 'dependencies.description AS dependence', 'users.id_profile', 'profiles.name AS profile', 'users.created_at')
                        ->join('cost_centers', 'users.id_cost_center', '=', 'cost_centers.id')
                        ->join('dependencies', 'users.id_dependence', '=', 'dependencies.id')
                        ->join('profiles', 'users.id_profile', '=', 'profiles.id')                            
                        ->orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();

    $message = $this->sendResponse($users, 'List of users');

    return $message;
}
```

**Relationships in my user model:**

```
public function cost_center()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(CostCenter::class, 'id_cost_center');
}  


public function dependence()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Dependence::class, 'id_dependence');
}


public function profile() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class, 'id_profile');
}
```

**Relationships in the other tables:**

**CostCenter:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id_cost_center');
}
```

**Dependence:**

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id_dependence');
}
```

**Profile:**

```
public function users() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id_profile');
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "username": "admin",
        "status": 1,
        "id_cost_center": 1,
        "code_cost_center": "001",
        "cost_center": "Admin",
        "id_dependence": 1,
        "dependence": "System",
        "id_profile": 1,
        "profile": "Developer",
        "created_at": "2021-09-13T11:26:46.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "username": "user",
        "status": 1,
        "id_cost_center": 2,
        "code_cost_center": "002",
        "cost_center": "Service",
        "id_dependence": 2,
        "dependence": "Store",
        "id_profile": 2,
        "profile": "Aux",
        "created_at": "2021-09-13T11:26:46.000000Z"
    }
],
"message": "List of users"
```

}

I have tried to create a user collection class but it only generates the users but not the relations:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
    ];
}
```

It only shows me the user data, I would like to be able to get the same answer that I get in the first normal query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things you could do:

1. Always return the relations when the user model is called:

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $with = ['cost_center', 'profile', 'dependence'];

    // ...
}
```

This will always return the user with the relations.

2. Only return relations when `toArray` is used.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection->with('cost_center'),
    ];
}
```

3. Just do this in the controller.

```
    $users = User::with('cost_center', 'profile', 'dependance')->get();
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried to do it with method 3, but it brings me all the related data, how can I do it so that it only shows me certain data, example: "cost_center": "Admin", "dependence": "New"

That is, as it shows in the first answer. Is there a way to better order the answer that returns me

Comment: It would be answer 2, with toArray and manually building the object